# In which class should I put operations in UML

Tags: uml, class-diagram, operation

I am working on a class diagram for a forum and I got some questions about classes' operations. In fact I don't know where should i put the operations

In my diagram a "pseudo" can create a topic. In my first solution. I put the operation createTopic() in the class pseudo, because he's the "actor" of this action

[Solution 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUWJY.png)
But after some thinking another way seems also coherent. I could remove the operation createTopic() from the Pseudo Class and create an operation on the class topic: create()

[Solution 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOBww.png)
Where solution should I pick ?
Do you have some rules or some "sentence" to use in order to decide what is the right solution to pick ?

Thank you very much guys

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to create a new `Topic` instance, that can definitely not be in `Topic` itself. It's rather a method in `pseudo` (you should keep naming conventions an start that with an upper case P) which invokes `new` on `Topic` and puts that somewhere in a collection inside `pseudo`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Thomas :)